# Консоль отображает у объекта новое значение ключа раньше, чем ключ получает это значение

Tags: javascript

Написал простой пример с изменением объекта в функции при передаче по ссылке. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/kR9zRc0Y...

```
var salaries = {
    "Вася": 100,
    "Петя": 300,
    "Даша": 250
};

function changeObject(object) {
    for (var key in object) {
        object[key] += 100;
    }
}

console.log(salaries);
changeObject(salaries);
console.log(salaries);
```

В итоге результат:

```
Object {Вася: 100, Петя: 300, Даша: 250}
Object {Вася: 200, Петя: 400, Даша: 350}
```

Передача по ссылке происходит, но `console.log()` отрабатывает не так как ожидается, как будто Chrome (Version 49.0.2623.110 (64-bit)) фиксирует состояние объекта на момент `console.log()`, хотя вроде должен ссылаться на один и тот же измененный объект.

Кто знает в чем может быть дело?

Comment: А что не так? был массив объектов, вывели, каждый элемент +100, вывели, вроде бы всё правильно.  Я про JS не особо знаю.

Comment: Ну так вы же сами изменили значения каждого поля на 100. Все правильно вам показало вроде как. Какой результат вы ожидали увидеть?

Comment: вобще-то всё работает как надо, а что должно было произойти ????

Comment: Ваш код отрабатывает так, как должен. Думаю вам стоит добавить еще и вывод, который вы **ожидаете** увидеть.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Суть заключается в том, как работает консоль в хроме. И конкретно, функция `log`.

Она выводит значение объекта в момент вывода, при этом, если для вывода всех свойств требуется много места, появляется возможность развернуть объект.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом можно заметить, что в свернутом виде будет показываться информация актуальная на момент вывода, но если развернуть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

будет показано состояния объекта на момент разворачивания.

Чтобы избежать такой неоднозначности, можно использовать

`console.dir`

Comment: Да вы, наверное, телепат =)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, что есть, то есть :) ну и на английской версии обычно спрашиваю почему при развороте не совпадает значение, этакий _обратный_ вопрос к этому

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, ваш ответ именно то, что я хотел узнать. Не знал про такую особенность консоли.

Comment: Это не особенность консоли , а особенность хрома при работе с выводом на консоль, то что в заголовке это нормальный вывод console.log, а то что стрелочкой это уже хром прилепливает своим встроенным дебаггером, и там уже ссылка на объект

Comment: @vnn198,  это как-то противоречит фразе: _как работает консоль в хроме_? :)

Comment: @Grundy консоль в хроме и функция log в том числе работает как и заложено в стандарте ECMA, и если бы дебаггер не прилеплял в стрелочке ссылку на объект, а тупо копировал вывод console.log то всё было бы весьма логично и понятно

Answer (score 0):

Можно развернуть через JSON:

> console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. в частности, стоит изложить, каким именно образом написанное вами отвечает на вопрос.