# forEach возвращает undefined после перебора массива, полученного из БД Web Sql

Tags: javascript, sql, массивы, websqldatabase

Вот код получения данных из БД и записи их в массив:

```
/*...*/
db.init.getArrOrder = function () {

        var database = db.init.db;
        var arr = [];

        database.transaction(function(tx){

            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM ClientsAll", [], function(tx,result){

                arr.splice(0,arr.length);

                for (var i=0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {

                    var obj = {

                        orderNumber: result.rows.item(i).get_numberOrder,
                        todayDate: result.rows.item(i).get_date
                    };

                    arr.push(obj);
                }

            });
            clientBD.numberOfOrder(arr);
        });
    };
/*...*/
```

Вот функция, которая получает этот массив:

```
  numberOfOrder: function (arr) {

            var arr = arr;

            console.log(arr);

            console.log(arr.forEach(function (item, i) {

                console.log(item);
            }));

           // arr.forEach(function (item, i) {
           //
           //     console.log(item);
           // });
        },
```

И вот в чем вся соль - массив не пустой, первый консоль.лог выводит массив, а второй - undefined. Почему undefined, если там есть объекты со свойствами?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Метод forEach возвращает `undefined`, а вы чего хотели?

Comment: @Darth что бы он перебрал не пустой массив и вывел в консоль item

Comment: ознакомьтесь, вот почему вы в консоли видите элементы массива, а forEach ничего не перебирает - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509990/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-javascript-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все функции WebSQL асинхронные. Данные можно брать только внутри функции обработчика результата. Т.е. вызов функции `executeSql()` отправляет запрос в базу и тут же возвращает управление. В итоге строка `clientBD.numberOfOrder(arr);` выполняется еще до того, как получены данные.

Используйте результаты внутри функции обработчика ответа БД:

```
     tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM ClientsAll", [], function(tx,result){
            ... формирование arr ....
            clientBD.numberOfOrder(arr);
        });
```

При этом консоль отладки ведет себя неожиданно, вы успеваете увидеть уже готовый результат, когда печатаете просто `console.log(arr)`. Но сравните как именно он его печатает. Если вы сделаете массив и тут же примените console.log то увидите сначала строку `[содержимое массива]` а при ее разворачивании уже по элементам. Тут же вы видите пустые `[]`, в момент вывода массив был еще пуст ! Но в момент когда вы его мышкой разворачиваете в нем уже есть данные ...

Comment: Мда, и ведь даже не попробовал это вариант. Спасибо, все работает!