# Как присвоить результат fetch переменной?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

```
fetch('./products.json')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
    });
```

Данная конструкция дает вот такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прекрасно, получили массив объектов, как и было задумано. Но! Как присвоить этот массив переменной?

Делал так:

```
json = fetch(url).then((res) => {return res.json()})
```

Здесь видно, что есть наш массив, но как его достать? Я не понимаю синтаксис `[[PromiseValue]]` и, если написать это, как литерал, будет ошибка (`.[[PromiseValue]]`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал так:

```
let json;
fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        json = data;
    });
```

`json` будет `undefined`

Подскажите, как результат `fetch` присвоить переменной. Спасибо!

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/promise результат fetch это промис

Comment: Смотря как вы планируете использовать дальше эту переменную ... `json = data;` - это у вас работает, вот только процесс асинхронный и вы присваиваете значение несколько позже, нежели ожидаете.

Comment: @Darth у тебя эта ссылка в закладках? 

Comment: @AlexeyTen Нет, в автозаполнении) ни дня без этого вопроса

Comment: А насчет ссылок в закладках, рекомендую тс посмотреть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509990/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-javascript-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5