# Почему getComputedStyle() отдает пустую строку во Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Для тренировки пишу простенький таймер на Vue.js
Столкнулся с ошибкой при которой window.getComputedStyle отдаёт для свойства fontSize пустую строку, хотя для требуемого элемента объект содержит это свойство, просто полтергейст какой-то...

Вот HTML:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  Vue.directive("timer", {
    bind(el, options) {

      let timer;
      let need_steps = Infinity; // Количество шагов таймера, которые необходимо сделать
      let do_steps = 0; // Количество шагов таймера, которые уже сделаны

      for (name in options.modifiers) {
        if (!isNaN(+name)) {
          need_steps = parseInt(name);
        }
      }

      if (options.modifiers.run) {
        options.value.call(this, el);
        do_steps++;
      }


    }
  });

  new Vue({
    el: ".sample",
    methods: {
      onTimer(el) {
        let computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(el);
        let curr_font_size = parseInt(computedStyle['fontSize']); // computedStyle.fontSize и computedStyle.getPropertyValue('font-size') тоже NaN
        console.log(computedStyle); // Содержит объект со стилями
        console.log(curr_font_size); // <----- NaN, никак не получается получить значение fontSize

      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.sample div {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="sample">
  <div v-timer:1000.5="onTimer">1</div>
  <div v-timer:1000.5.run="onTimer">2</div>
  <div v-timer:1000="onTimer">3</div>
</div>
```

В итоге в переменной computedStyle присутствует объект со стилями, но переменная curr_font_size пуста, в ней ничего нет. Почему?? Как в этом случае получить font-size?

Comment: ты уверен, что именно значения _computedStyle.fontSize и computedStyle.getPropertyValue('font-size')_ - NaN, а не результат parseInt?

Comment: проблема заключается в том, что метод `OnTimer` вызывается слишком рано. Элемент еще не добавлен в DOM, следовательно к нему еще не применялись стили из родительского элемента (так как у дива его еще нет) поэтому текущий стиль не установлен.

Comment: Это точно vue? Или от него тут только название? Не видел никогда чтобы настолько неправильно его использовали

Comment: @MoloF, это абсолютно точно vue, флудите в другом месте

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо. Заменил хук bind на хук inserted и всё заработало. Больше всего напрягало то, что console.log(computedStyle); содержал нужное свойство с искомым значением (14px), но на следующей строке в console.log(curr_font_size); переменная curr_font_size оказывалась пуста. Если стили из родительского элемента ещё не применились, тогда почему в переменной computedStyle был объект с уже рассчитанными стилями?

Comment: подробнее смотри [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510027/186999)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема что елемен не был приатачен в документ, используй другой евент inserted:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Hook-Functions

```js
window.onload = function() {

  Vue.directive("timer", {
    bind(el, options) {

      let timer;
      let need_steps = Infinity; // Количество шагов таймера, которые необходимо сделать
      let do_steps = 0; // Количество шагов таймера, которые уже сделаны

      for (name in options.modifiers) {
        if (!isNaN(+name)) {
          need_steps = parseInt(name);
        }
      }

      if (options.modifiers.run) {
        options.value.call(this, el);
        do_steps++;
      }


    }
  });

  new Vue({
    el: ".sample",
    methods: {
      onTimer(el) {
        let computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(el);
        let curr_font_size = parseInt(computedStyle['fontSize']); // computedStyle.fontSize и computedStyle.getPropertyValue('font-size') тоже NaN
        console.log(computedStyle); // Содержит объект со стилями
        console.log(curr_font_size); // <----- NaN, никак не получается получить значение fontSize
        let inDom = document.body.contains(el);
        console.log(inDom); // <- будет false
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.sample div {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="sample">
  <div v-timer:1000.5="onTimer">1</div>
  <div v-timer:1000.5.run="onTimer">2</div>
  <div v-timer:1000="onTimer">3</div>
</div>
```