# Решение задачи сортировка людей в парке по росту

Tags: javascript

Вчера на сайте [codesignal](https://codesignal.com/) решал интересное задание сортировка людей по их росту в парке не трогая деревья.

В парке есть люди разного роста и деревья задача отсортировать людей не трогая деревья.

Вход дается массив такого рода `[-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180]` на выходе надо получить такой массив `[-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 190]`.

**-1** (деревья) не трогаем остальное сортируем.

Я сделал данную задачу может и криво но вопрос не в этом.Вопрос в том что лучший ответ был следующий

```js
const arr = [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180];

function sortByHeight(a) {
    var s = a.filter(h => h > 0).sort((a, b) => a - b);
    console.log(s);
    return a.map(p => {
        if (p !== -1) {
            return s.shift();
        }
        return -1;
    })
} 
console.log(sortByHeight(arr)); // [-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 190]
```

И мне очень трудно понять его работу.

То есть почему если написать `console.log(s)` после вот этой строки `var s = a.filter(h => h > 0).sort((a, b) => a - b)` мне показывает пустой массив ?

Там же должно быть что то вроде вот такого массива

```
[150, 160, 170, 180, 190]
```

Почему он удаляет первый элемент пустого массива вот тут `return s.shift();`?
Надо чтобы кто нибудь объяснил работу этого кода полностью.Спасибо заранее.

Comment: вы сделали сниппет, вот возьмите и добавьте туда вывод `s`. как по мне выводит нужный массив.

Comment: @teran https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-cartwright-xox0r

Comment: зы: мы получаем массив в ростом после фильтрации. затем его сортируем. далее идем по исходному, если `-1` то оставляем, иначе берем первый элемент из сортированных/ `shift` удаляет первый и возвращает его. То есть нам просто нужно каждый раз делать такой сдвиг, и будем получать нужные значения в нужном порядке.

Comment: во втором цикле (map), идет замена элементов исходного цикла из уже отфильтрованного

Comment: добавил `console.log` здесь в сниппет в вопросе. все работает как и ожидается.

Comment: Вы видете пустой `console.log`, потому что браузер отображает последнее значение массива, а в Вашем случае - из этого массива уже удалены (`s.shift()`) все элементы

Comment: @Дмытрык там лог сразу после фильтрации и сортировки, с чего вдруг последнее?

Comment: @teran, если мы будем в консоле браузера смотреть, то увидем пустой лог. А в сниппете, видимо,  лог через сереализацию проходит

Comment: Все понятно, первым делом мы в функции отсеиваем значения которые меньше 1, потом сортируем массив и передаем его в переменную s. И потом сразу же делаем возврат измененного массива, который в случае если текущий элемент не -1, то берется 1 значение из s, а там у нас уже остортированный массив без -1.

Comment: @teran почему ответ не написал?

Comment: @teran, по поводу _с чего последнее_: [Странное поведение Javascript при передаче объекта по ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510027/186999)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Разбор кода по порядку. Первая строка

```js
var s = a.filter(h => h > 0).sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

Метод `filter` отсеивает все элементы, которые меньше 0, в нашем случае это деревья

```js
[-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180] ==> [150, 190, 170, 160, 180]
```

Метод `sort`, соответственно, сортирует. Стрелочная функция, переданная в `sort` должна возвращать отрицательное число, если левый меньше правого, положительное, если больше, и ноль, если они равны. `a - b` подходит.

```js
[150, 190, 170, 160, 180] ==> [150, 160, 170, 180, 190]
```

Следующее выражение

```js
return a.map(p => {
    if (p !== -1) {
        return s.shift();
    }
    return -1;
})
```

Метод `map` итеративно применяет переданную в него функцию к элементам массива.
При этом проход осуществляется именно по исходному массиву `a`, заметьте.

Метод `shift` как бы "вырезает" первый элемент массива, "сдвигая" весь массив на 1 элемент влево (отсюда и название `shift`). При этом вырезанный элемент возвращается методом.

В функции если текущий элемент `p` не является деревом (не равен `-1`), то вместо него возвращается первый элемент отсортированного массива `s`.

Так как массив `s` уже отсортирован, первый его элемент будет всегда наименьшим, благодаря чему можно по порядку брать элементы из начала массива `s` с помощью `shift`
и получить отсортированный массив снова.

Вот наглядный пример работы этого алгоритма:

```
1: [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180]
     ^

2: [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180] <== [150, 160, 170, 180, 190]
         ^                                     ^

3: [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180] <== [160, 170, 180, 190]
              ^                                ^

4: [-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180] <== [170, 180, 190]
                   ^                           ^

5: [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180]
                        ^

6: [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180]
                            ^

7: [-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180] <== [180, 190]
                                ^              ^

8: [-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 180] <== [190]
                                     ^         ^

РЕЗУЛЬТАТ: [-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 190]
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ отлично объяснили.