# Заполненный массив объектов возвращает lenght = 0

Tags: javascript, массивы, typescript, angular, async-await

Я выполняю запросы к серверу и добавляю их в массив объектов в сервисе:

```
async auth(login: string, password: string) {
    let data = this.ApiService.autorization(login, password);
    data = (isNullOrUndefined(await data)) ? [] : await data;
    this.ApiService.cars = data['cars'];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.ApiService.cars.length; i++) {
        let car = this.ApiService.cars[i];
        this.http.get('http://get/example/').subscribe((data) => {
            this.ApiService.carsPosition.push(data[0]);
        });
    }
  console.log(this.ApiService.carsPosition)
  console.log('lenght: ' + this.ApiService.carsPosition.length)
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные получены, но их длина равна нолю. И я не могу их использовать. Что делать?

Попробывал сделать данным способом:

```html
var observables = [];
for (let i = 0; i < this.ApiService.cars.length; i++) {
    observables.push(this.http.get('http://get/example/').pipe(map(data=>data[0])))
}
Observable.forkJoin(observables).subscribe(cars =>{
    this.ApiService.carsPosition = cars;
    console.log(this.ApiService.carsPosition)
    console.log('lenght: ' + this.ApiService.carsPosition.length)
})
```

Массив я получаю, но forkJoin не выполняется.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: У меня запросы в цикле идут обычным observable http request (angular)

Answer (score 4):

Проблема в асинхронном запросе `this.http.get('http://get/example/')`.

Так как запрос асинхронный, обработчик subscribe выполняется после выхода из цикла, поэтому в момент вызова console.log, массив действительно пуст.

<sub>Подробнее про то, почему при раскрытии показываются верные значения ответе на вопрос [Странное поведение Javascript при передаче объекта по ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510027/186999)</sub>

Для решения можно собрать все запросы в массив, и с помощью метода `.forkJoin` дождаться результата:

```
var observables = [];
for (let i = 0; i < this.ApiService.cars.length; i++) {
    observables.push(this.http.get('http://get/example/').pipe(map(data=>data[0])))
}
Observable.forkJoin(observables).subscribe(cars =>{
    this.ApiService.carsPosition = cars;
    console.log(this.ApiService.carsPosition)
    console.log('lenght: ' + this.ApiService.carsPosition.length)
})
```

Comment: Попробывал сделать, не получилось. forkJoin не выполняется. Ответил в вопросе.

Comment: @Optimus, какая версия ангуляра? попробуй `.forkJoin(...observables)` - они в одной из версий поменяли способо передачи параметра

Comment: @Optimus что значит "forkJoin не выполнятся"? В консоли ты ведь получил "console.log(carsPosition)". Создай _минимальный воспроизводимый пример_.

Comment: @overthesanity, там Observables элементы массива, а не значения в результате, думаю об этом речь

Comment: @Grundy я видел, но такого быть не может с тем кодом, который ты привел в ответе. Что-то автор скрывает от нас :)

Comment: @overthesanity, я думаю может для старой версии, где передавать надо отдельными параметрами каждый observable, а не одним массивом

Answer (score 0):

Можно после получения данных проверить значение `i`

```
async auth(login: string, password: string) {
  let data = this.ApiService.autorization(login, password);
  data = (isNullOrUndefined(await data)) ? [] : await data;
  this.ApiService.cars = data['cars'];

  let stop = this.ApiService.cars.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < stop; i++) {
    let car = this.ApiService.cars[i];
    this.http.get('http://get/example/').subscribe((data) => {
      this.ApiService.carsPosition.push(data[0]);

      if (i === stop - 1) finish.call(this); // <-
    });
  }

  function finish() {
    console.log(this.ApiService.carsPosition)
    console.log('lenght: ' + this.ApiService.carsPosition.length)
  }
}
```

Comment: Работает, выводит массив уже определенный длины, но после того как хочу использовать его в другом компоненте, все равно показывает 0