# Баг Google Chrome или неправильный код? Неправильно получает значения ширины и высоты картинки

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Ребят, столкнулся с такой проблемой, я делаю простой вьювер изображений и в одном моменте мне просто нужна ширина значения изображения для анимации. Но суть вот в чём.

Есть вот такой кусок кода:

```
animate(from, to, func, duration) {
    self = this;

    let beginTop = from.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    let beginLeft = from.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    let beginWidth = from.getBoundingClientRect().width;

    let endTop = to.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    let endLeft = to.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    let endWidth = to.getBoundingClientRect().width;

    console.dir(to);
    console.log(to.clientWidth, to.naturalWidth);
    console.log(to.getBoundingClientRect())

    let deltaTop = endTop - beginTop;
    let deltaLeft = endLeft - beginLeft;
    let deltaWidth = endWidth - beginWidth;
    ...
```

Здесь я получаю свойства изображения, в данном случае мне нужна ширина. Попробовал двумя способами, через функцию и напрямую. Так вот, в остальных браузерах все значения выводят корректно, кроме Google Chrome, он выводит ширину и высоты по нулям.
При этом вроде бы видно, что в console.dir(to) он вроде бы выводит значения ширины и высоты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но строкой ниже, когда получаешь свойство напрямую, он выдаёт их по нулям.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вообще понять? Мой косяк или косяк хрома?? Так как в остальных браузерах значения выводит почему-то корректно.

Есть видеофайл с демонстрацией проблемы. https://ru.files.fm/f/8ms9hnma

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Странное поведение Javascript при передаче объекта по ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509990/%d0%a1%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-javascript-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Comment: Это не совсем то, дело в том, что неважно, что мы выводим в консоль, а то, что свойство ширины для одного и того же кода выводится по разному в разных браузерах. Там нет ответа на этот вопрос.

Comment: нули выводит, потому что в момент вывода в консоль данных о ширине и высоте еще нет. Но потом, когда Вы смотрите объект картинки, эти данные уже есть. Ответ, на вопрос, почему так - находится по ссылке, что я дал выше

Comment: Ответ оказался тривиальнее) Перед всеми операциями надо просто было добавить onload, да. Картинка просто не успела прогружаться и данных не было. Однако почему именно в console.dir он уже выводил эти данные до загрузки, немного смутило. Как будто эти данные были изменены или получены реактивно сами по себе после загрузки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была по моей вине. Перед всеми манипуляциями с картинками и перед вставкой её в DOM нужно обрабатывать всё через onload обработчик. Однако почему console.dir вывел эти данные до загрузки, немного смутило и немного непонятно для меня.

Comment: «почему console.dir вывел эти данные до загрузки» — потому что он ленивый и подгружает содержимое объекта только в момент разворачивания списка, а к этому моменту картинка уже успевает загрузиться и имеет размеры

Answer (score 0):

Свойство `Element.clientWidth` равно 0 для инлайн элементов и элементов без CSS.

Более подробно [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth)

С `naturalWidth` тоже есть варианты, когда по умолчанию возвращается 0.
[Проверьте](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalWidth), не ваш ли это случай.

Comment: В том и дело, что стили применены и этот элемент блочный. Тогда бы навярняка такое поведение не работало бы во всех браузерах, если так написано в спецификации.