# Javascript magic

Tags: javascript

Магия жаваскрипта

[Этот не тот ответ.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509990/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-javascript-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5)
Тут проблема с консоль логом. А у меня проблема в том что из объекта пропадает значение. И да оно именно пропадает так, как на сервер оно тоже не приходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да можно заметить что при **stringify** номер тупо испаряется.

Если хоть у кого-то есть какие-то предположения, говорите, возможно это натолкнет на мысль.

Comment: перечитай еще раз ответ в дубликате. Это не у тебя пропадает, это между выводом и открытием этого объекта в консоли добавляется.

Comment: Чтобы проверить, просто выведи `console.log('tel', formSend.tel)` и посмотри что тебе выведется

Comment: @Grundy Как оно может добавится если код выполняется последовательно. Я сделал скриншот двух последовательных строк. По вашему в первой строчке элемент уже добавлен а на 2 еще добавляется? Я пробовал вариант из ответа, это не помогает.

Comment: И комментарий тоже перечитай :-) Добавляется НЕ между строк, а между выполнением console.log, и тем, когда ты в консоли нажал на треугольник и распахнул объект.

Comment: _Я пробовал вариант из ответа, это не помогает._ - а какой вариант был в ответе? В ответе просто поясняется **почему** так происходит, а не какие-то варианты решения.

Comment: @Grundy По вашему вариант с console.dir там не предлагают?

Comment: Суть в том, что **после** `console.log` у вас есть код вида `formSend.tel = "some_string";` И консоль может это обнаружить при раскрытии объекта (кликнули треугольничек, консоль подгрузила _актуальное_ состояние объекта). Если же никакого присваивания `tel` _после_ `console.log` нет, то приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @makcim512, да, забыл про эту строчку :) в любом случае причины ошибки это не меняет. Да и на самом деле при использовании `.dir` просто нет предварительного вывода объекта. Поэтому убирается неоднозначность в том, что до раскрытия и после разные данные показываются.

Comment: Вопросы одинаковые. Если вы считаете, что проблема в чём-то другом, то составьте [mcve] который продемонстрирует проблему и даст понять что это действительно другой вопрос