# странное поведение jquery объекта (или класса?)

Tags: jquery

Имею объект (может это класс?) $.Multicon в котором есть side_id
делаю так:

```
console.log('сейчас открыт $.Multicon.side_id ' + $.Multicon.side_id); //сейчас открыт $.Multicon.side_id 5
console.log($.Multicon); //side_id равен 6
console.log('сейчас открыт $.Multicon.side_id ' + $.Multicon.side_id); //сейчас открыт $.Multicon.side_id 5
```

что это за поведение такое и как такое возможно? $.Multicon.side_id - это ид холста и у меня логика неверно из-за этой странности работает

[image: о]

Comment: Возможно из-за этого - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509990/%d0%a1%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-javascript-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b5

Comment: нет, дело не только в самом side_id это реально другой объект и я проверил вариант с dir - не работает

Comment: магии не бывает. вы видите состояние объекта в другой момент времени.

Comment: я понимаю, но это другой объект. Я в цикле рисую на холсте и этот side_id - это ид холста и он не просто в консоли "старый", он и рисует не на том холсте. А ещё магия в том, что если после цикла (в котором уже всё должно быть нарисовано на холстах) сменить ид холста на 5-й, то обе картинки будут нарисованы на 5-м ид, фак мой мозг

Comment: вы можете добавить сниппет, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему?

Comment: как это можно сделать?