# Не могу получить массив jquery из json

Tags: jquery

Получаю данные из php

```
let pars,  lastMonth = [];

$.post('data.php',data => {
pars = $.parseJSON(data);

for(let prop in pars)
lastMonth.push(pars[prop]);
});
```

Через консоль смотрю

```
console.log(lastMonth);
```

Вроде как массив НО если сделать так

```
console.log(lastMonth[0]);
```

то undefined.

Что делаю не так?

[image: фото1]

```
[![фото2][2]][2]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: фото3]

Comment: «если сделать так» — сделать где и когда? Это важно, ведь массив заполняется не мгновенно

Comment: Массив заполняется, я же не писал, что он НЕ ЗАПОЛНЯЕТСЯ, еще раз, если  console.log(lastMonth); то я вижу массив НО если я обращаюсь по индексу console.log(lastMonth[0]); то undefined

Comment: Ещё раз: где и когда? Покажите код, в котором вы делаете console.log; если в браузерной консоли — покажите скриншот вашего ввода

Comment: Если пытаться запустить близкий к вашему код целиком в консоли, то всё работает нормально, `lastMonth[0]` успешно выводит значение из массива, ваша проблема не воспроизводится https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zgdo.png

Comment: Скрины добавил.

Comment: А теперь попробуйте сделать `console.log(JSON.stringify(lastMonth))` и вы увидите, что массив на самом деле НЕ ЗАПОЛНЯЕТСЯ, потому что вы вызываете console.log слишком рано и не дожидаетесь момента, когда он заполнится.

Comment: Объяснение того, почему без JSON.stringify массив выглядит якобы заполненым, есть здесь: [Странное поведение Javascript при передаче объекта по ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509990)

Comment: О том, как всё-таки дождаться заполнения массива: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290)

Comment: И да, ещё рекомендую для наглядности воспользоваться отладчиком и поставить точку останова на этом console.log — он приостановит выполнение страницы, и тогда даже без JSON.stringify вы в отладчике сможете увидеть, что массив на самом деле ещё не успел заполниться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Массив это ссылочный тип**, выводя его в консоль он при открытии будет иметь актуальные данные, то есть, пока ты выводил пустой массив и нажимал на кнопку раскрыть, он успел его заполнить и отобразить то что в нем находится на момент открытия а не на момент выполнения. Для наглядности выведи массив через JSON.stringify.

А решение собственно это - дождаться выполнения асинхронного кода и потом оперировать полученным значением. Например так

```
async function doRequest() {
    const months = await new Promise(resolve => {
        $.post('data.php',data => {
            const lastMonth = [];
            pars = $.parseJSON(data);
    
            for(let prop in pars)
                lastMonth.push(pars[prop]);

            resolve(lastMonth);
        });
    });

    console.log(months);
}

doRequest();
```

Comment: Пробывал так, не работает
let lastMonth = [];
fetch('data.php')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(pars => {
 for(let prop in pars){lastMonth.push(pars[prop])};
});
console.log(lastMonth[0]);

Comment: Ваш код выдаёт ошибку lastMonth is not defined

Comment: @spoon100500 в этом вашем пробовании та же самая ошибка что и с jquery — вы выполняете console.log слишком рано и не пытаетесь дождаться момента, когда fetch примет ответ на запрос и заполнит массив

Comment: Ваш код выдаёт ошибку lastMonth is not defined?

Comment: @spoon100500 обновил ответ

Comment: А разве then() не выполняет ожидание?

Comment: @spoon100500 нет, then просто добавляет функцию-обработчик и мгновенно завершает работу, ничего не ожидая

Comment: then выполнит ожидание текущего промиса, но не текущей строки кода, и передаст значение в лямбду, то есть, запрос запускается параллельно выполнению твоего кода, пока запрос идет, интерпретатор уже переходит к строке console.log, и уже потом учитывая что запрос выполняется дольше, сначала произойдет вывод в консоль а потом запись в lastMonths.

Comment: Спасибо, ох уж эти промисы))

Comment: months находится внутри doRequest() т.е. doRequest() это набор промисов, как присвоить результат переменной? Добавил фото3.

Comment: @spoon100500 снаружи doRequest — никак, в javascript это принципиально невозможно

Comment: ...ну или разве что [top-level await](https://habr.com/ru/post/524068/) использовать, если он поддерживается во всех нужных браузерах